# CSS hexadecimal RGBA?

Tags: css, colors, rgba

I know you can write ...

```css
background-color: #ff0000;
```

... if you want something that is red.

And you can write ...

```css
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

... if you want something red and translucent.

Is there any terse way of writing partially transparent colors in hexadecimal? I want something like:

```css
background-color: #ff000088; <--- the 88 is the alpha
```

... or ...

```css
background-color: #ff0000 50%;
```

I am getting all my colors in hexadecimal, and having to convert them all to the decimal 0-255 scale is annoying.

Comment: You may experiment with different notations, but I didn't succedd. `rgb(0xff,\x80,#44)` astonishingly Octal representation seem to york a little bit `rgb(0100, 0200,0300)` is `#4080C0`

Comment: You may want to use ColorPic, which shows the decimal figures for a picked color http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/

Comment: As Slomojo suggested, in LESS you can do background-color: #ff0000 + rgba(0, 0, 0, .8); which will convert the hex for you and still apply the transparency but this can't be done using native CSS.

Comment: Using the `opacity` css property works for me, as Charming Prince suggest below.

Comment: For completeness, as Slomojo and fl3x7 discuss, [this can be done in Sass easily](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html): `background-color: opacify(#ff0000, 0.5);` or `background-color: transparentize(#ff0000, 0.5);` You can supply Sass hex color variables to those Sass functions as well.

Comment: @fl3x7 I tried #ff0000 + rgba(0,0,0,0.8); using LESS but it didn't work. The result was still hex. Maybe a browser issue. However, in LESS there is a fade function that works. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31145242/179412) below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hex representation of a color with alpha channel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419448/hex-representation-of-a-color-with-alpha-channel)

Comment: PostCSS library, but I believe this goes outside of future-proof standards. Still gets the notation with a preprocessor... https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-hexrgba

Comment: This tool is perfect for hexadecimal to rgba conversion : https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/ECECEC
Check the CMYK line to get infos.

Comment: See which browsers support #rrggbbaa notation... https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa

Answer (score 172):

## The CSS Color Module Level 4 will *probably* support 4 and 8-digit hexadecimal RGBA notation!

Three weeks ago (18th of December 2014) the **[CSS Color Module Level 4 editor's draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color)** was submitted to the  CSS W3C Working Group. Though in a state which is heavily susceptible to change, the current version of the document implies that in the *somewhat* near future CSS will support both the 4 and 8-digit hexadecimal RGBA notation.

*Note: the following quote has irrelevant chunks cut out and the source may have been heavily modified by the time you read this (as mentioned above, it's an editor's draft and not a finalised document).
If things have heavily changed, please leave a comment letting me know so I can update this answer!*

> ## *[§](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#hex-notation)* 4.2. The RGB hexadecimal notations: #RRGGBB
>
> The syntax of a `<hex-color>` is a `<hash-token>` token **whose value consists of 3, 4, 6, or 8 hexadecimal digits**. In other words, a hex color is written as a hash character, "#", followed by some number of digits `0-9` or letters `a-f` (the case of the letters doesn’t matter - `#00ff00` is identical to `#00FF00`).
>
> ### 8 digits
>
> The first 6 digits are interpreted identically to the 6-digit notation. The last pair of digits, interpreted as a hexadecimal number, specifies the alpha channel of the color, where `00` represents a fully transparent color and `ff` represent a fully opaque color.
>
> > **Example 3**
> > In other words, `#0000ffcc` represents the same color as `rgba(0, 0, 100%, 80%)` (a slightly-transparent blue).
>
> ### 4 digits
>
> This is a shorter variant of the 8-digit notation, "expanded" in the same way as the 3-digit notation is. The first digit, interpreted as a hexadecimal number, specifies the red channel of the color, where `0` represents the minimum value and `f` represents the maximum. The next three digits represent the green, blue, and alpha channels, respectively.

### What does this mean for the future of CSS colours?

This means that assuming this isn't completely removed from the Level 4 document, we'll soon be able to define our RGBA colours (or HSLA colours, if you're one of *those* guys) in hexadecimal format in browsers which support the Color Module Level 4's syntax.

#### Example

```css
elem {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);           /* RGB notation (no alpha). */
    background: #000;                   /* 3-digit hexadecimal notation (no alpha). */
    background: #000000;                /* 6-digit hexadecimal notation (no alpha). */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);     /* RGBA notation. */

    /* The new 4 and 8-digit hexadecimal notation. */
    background: #0000;                  /* 4-digit hexadecimal notation. */
    background: #00000000;              /* 8-digit hexadecimal notation. */
}
```

### When will I be able to use this in my client-facing products?

[image: Tumble weed is the only real response...]

*All jokes aside:* it's currently only the start of 2015, so these will not be supported in any browser for quite some time yet - even if your product is only designed to work on the most up-to-date of browsers you'll probably not be seeing this in action in a production browser any time soon.

[View current browser support for #RRGGBBAA color notation](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa)

However, that said, the way CSS works means that we can actually start using these today! If you really want to start using them right now, as long as you add a fall back any non-supporting browsers will simply ignore the new properties until they are deemed valid:

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  
  /* Fall back (...to browsers which don't support alpha transparency). */
  background: #FEFE7F;
  color: #3F3FFE;
  
  /* Current 'modern' browser support. */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);
  
  /* Fall... foward? */
  background: #ffff007F; /* Or, less accurately, #ff08 */
  color: #0000ffbe;      /* Or #00fc */
}
```

```html
<figure>Hello, world!</figure>
```

As long as you're viewing this answer on a browser which supports the `background` and `color` properties in CSS, the `<figure>` element in result of the above snippet will look very similar to this:

[image: Code Snippet Result Image]

Using the most recent version of Chrome on Windows (v39.0.2171) to inspect our `<figure>` element, we'll see the following:

[image: Element Inspector Example]

The 6-digit hexadecimal fall back is overridden by the `rgba()` values, and our 8-digit hexadecimal values are ignored as they are currently deemed invalid by Chrome's CSS parser. As soon as our browser supports these 8-digit values, these will override the `rgba()` ones.

**UPDATE 2018-07-04:** Firefox, Chrome and Safari are support this notation now, Edge still missing but will probably follow (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa).

Comment: I remember seeing this brought up in the mailing lists a year or so ago at the latest (the idea of having 4-/8-digit hex is nothing new). Glad to see it's entered Colors 4 for now.

Comment: @BoltClock hopefully it'll stay here, too!

Comment: [Firefox Nightly](https://twitter.com/ziyunfei/status/729896688534441988) has just gotten this implemented :)

Comment: `/* Fall... foward? */` » I suggest jumpforward. Fallback and jumpforward :^p

Comment: Just adding a useful link. Link contains opacity value list in hex. https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

Comment: What was the image that appeared here? It's been replaced by an "iStock" placeholder.

Comment: @AlexReinking for some stupid reason my work blocks Stack Overflow's image host. It should, off the top of my head, be an image of tumbleweed.

Comment: Note that the `rgba()` function is now considered legacy. They will standardize on `rgb()`. Here's the modern way to add the alpha value: `rgb(0 0 0 / 1)`. [Reference](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions)

Answer (score 115):

I found the answer after posting the enhancement to the question. Sorry!

MS Excel helped!

simply add the Hex prefix to the hex colour value to add an alpha that has the equivalent opacity as the % value.

(in rbga the percentage opacity is expressed as a decimal as mentioned above)

```
Opacity %   255 Step        2 digit HEX prefix
0%          0.00            00
5%          12.75           0C
10%         25.50           19
15%         38.25           26
20%         51.00           33
25%         63.75           3F
30%         76.50           4C
35%         89.25           59
40%         102.00          66
45%         114.75          72
50%         127.50          7F
55%         140.25          8C
60%         153.00          99
65%         165.75          A5
70%         178.50          B2
75%         191.25          BF
80%         204.00          CC
85%         216.75          D8
90%         229.50          E5
95%         242.25          F2
100%        255.00          FF
```

Comment: Don't relly understand. Do you mean `#FF00000C` is equivalent to `rgba(255,0,0,0.05)`?

Comment: @PointedEars wrong on both counts. The OP does not specifically mention CSS3, and this question I would have thought is likely to be more related to IE specific issues which we all know are difficult. None-the-less IE uses both CSS and Hex transparency values in it's CSS.

Comment: @T9b Nonsense. The OP has a **CSS** question about RGBA values. There is no RGBA support in CSS before CSS3. If IE/MSHTML supports your notation, then that is **proprietary**, not compatible, and inherently unreliable. And surely you are not suggesting to use client-side scripting to make that notation work, are you? For that would not be compatible and would be unreliable as well.

Comment: @T9b Of course, you can make that work reliably, with reduced compatibility, server-side. If so, the OP should state their environment and programming language  as there are far too many possibilities.

Comment: Firefox rounds color channels to integers and the alpha channel to thousandths. If I enter something as `rgba(127.5,127.5,127.5,0.5)`, I get `rgba(128,128,128,0.5)` and that's the same as `#80808080` in modern browsers that support rgba hex colors. `#7f7f7f7f` is translated to `rgba(127,127,127,0.498)`. This chart is otherwise correct, say at 20% (`#3333` = `#33333333` = `rgba(51,51,51,0.2)`) and at 60% (`#9999` = `#99999999` = `rgba(153,153,153,0.6)`).

Comment: Just for reference RGBA is now supported on most browsers as of 2022-08-01

Answer (score 48):

`#rrggbbaa` notation is fully supported in [Chrome 62+ and all other evergreen browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa):

```
background: #56ff0077;
```

Comment: I was excited to see this, and then tried it in devtools on Chrome 55. No dice, it errors as an invalid property value... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Looks like it has had various issues [here's](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5685348285808640) the status page for the feature.

Comment: Chrome has removed support, Safari and Firefox have support.  Do not use this.

Comment: As of July 2019, there are 84.5% of all browsers globally supporting this feature. https://caniuse.com/#search=rrggbbaa

Comment: I think it is once again working in latest chrome: Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Answer (score 27):

```
RGB='#ffabcd';
A='0.5';
RGBA='('+parseInt(RGB.substring(1,3),16)+','+parseInt(RGB.substring(3,5),16)+','+parseInt(RGB.substring(5,7),16)+','+A+')';
```

Comment: `var rgb = '#ffabcd'; var a = '0.5';
var matches = rgb.match(/#([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})/i);
var rgba = 'rgba(' + matches.slice(1).map(function(m) { return parseInt(m, 16); }).concat(a) + ')';`

Comment: If you are coming from a world of React:
```<div style={ { backgroundColor: `rgba(${ parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16) }, ${ parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16) }, ${ parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16) }, 0.5)` } }></div>```

Comment: You can use this tool to convert - https://kilianvalkhof.com/2016/css-html/css-hexadecimal-colors-with-transparency-a-conversion-tool/

Answer (score 24):

Sass has `red`, `green`, `blue` to extract to channels from a hex color:

```
background-color: rgba(red($hex_color), green($hex_color), blue($hex_color), 0.2);
```

Sass also has `rgba($hex_color, $alpha)`

Comment: SASS supports background-color: rgba($color, .2);

Comment: those are not valid css methods - you should mention that

Answer (score 16):

In Sass we can write:

```
background-color: rgba(#ff0000, 0.5);
```

as it was suggested in [Hex representation of a color with alpha channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419448/hex-representation-of-a-color-with-alpha-channel/13266076)

Comment: This is for Sass

Comment: The disadvantage is, that the original color - `#ff0000` - is modified and **the result** is then put in place in the final CSS file. This makes it impossible to control the alpha channel via e.g. a CSS3 variable.

Answer (score 14):

See here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color

It is not possible, most probably because 0xFFFFFFFF is greater than the maximum value for 32bit integers

Comment: `#ffffff` (six hex-digits) is actually a **24-bit** color value; 0xFFFFFFFF is actually 2³²−1, and can be represented as *unsigned* 32-bit integer.  I think the reason why `#ffffffff` (eight hex-digits) is not specified is both that CSS colors are rooted in sRGB color space and that an eight-hex-digit notation would be ambiguous with a display device that supports a color depth of 32 bit. Remember that there is still `#fff` so that it means `rgb(100%, 100%, 100%)` – white – both with a color depth of 8 bit (256 colors) and 16 bit (65536 or 64K colors).

Comment: Actually that's exactly what 32bit integer is capable to hold. 2 hex digits can hold as many values as 8 binary digits. Or... 8 hex digits can hold as many values as 32 binary digits.

Comment: Though there's no major reason the CSS function shouldn't have been designed this way from the start (as well as rgba(0.0, 0.5, 1.0) floats for normals to match the other color functions). As for 32-bit display color support, this doesn't exist with 6-digit RGB to begin with and is really an edge case. I don't have an issue with learning different formats, but there are cases where you may get a dynamic color in hex and need to create CSS from it at runtime. This requires the extra step of converting from hex to decimal if you want to add alpha to it, which is clunky.

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid that's not possible. the `rgba` format you know is the only one.

Comment: @mdmullinax: But who specifies hex colors in HSL notation?

Comment: I associate everything in life with HSLA notation, it's a version of synesthesia :)

Comment: @mdmullinax: Oh, that's actually pretty awesome!

Comment: @mdmullinax: This may delight you if you've not seen it yet: http://mothereffinghsl.com

Comment: @BoltClock I like that site, Paul Irish is win

Comment: @BoltClock - I use HSL and have for quite a while. Not everywhere but in some cases. Far easier than RGB.

Answer (score 7):

If you have all your colors in HEX variables, you can use the following SCSS code:

First, copy this mapping from rgba - opacity values to hex codes:

```
    $opacity-to-hex: (
    0: '00',
    0.05: '0C',
    0.1: '19',
    0.15: '26',
    0.2: '33',
    0.25: '3F',
    0.3: '4C',
    0.35: '59',
    0.4: '66',
    0.45: '72',
    0.5: '7F',
    0.55: '8C',
    0.6: '99',
    0.65: 'A5',
    0.7: 'B2',
    0.75: 'BF',
    0.8: 'CC',
    0.85: 'D8',
    0.9: 'E5',
    0.95: 'F2',
    1: 'FF'
)
```

Then copy the following mixin that uses the mapping:

```
@mixin color-opacity($property, $color, $opacity) {
    #{$property}: unquote($color + map-get($opacity-to-hex, $opacity));
}
```

Last but not least, you can use this mixin with the mapped opacity on all color-properties, e.g. like this:

```
@include color-opacity('background-color', $your_hex_color, 0.8);
@include color-opacity('color', $your_hex_color, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can use LESS, there is a fade function.

```
@my-opaque-color: #a438ab;
@my-semitransparent-color: fade(@my-opaque-color, 50%);

background-color:linear-gradient(to right,@my-opaque-color, @my-semitransparent-color); 

// result: 
background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #a438ab, rgba(164, 56, 171, 0.5));
```

Comment: and sass/scss has an equivalent function: `rgba(base-color, 0.5)`

Answer (score 4):

In **scss** you can use the following:

```
background-color: rgba($color: #000088, $alpha: 0.5);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Charming Prince:**

Only internet explorer allows the 4 byte hex color in the format of ARGB, where A is the Alpha channel. It can be used in gradient filters for example:

```
filter  : ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=@{dir},startColorstr=@{color1},endColorstr=@{color2})";
```

Where dir can be: 1(horizontal) or 0(vertical)
And the color strings can be hex colors(#FFAAD3) or argb hex colors(#88FFAAD3).

Answer (score 0):

Well, different color notations is what you will have to learn.
[Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com) gives you a better chance to find color and in multiple notations. 
 Hex is not different from RGB, FF = 255 and 00 = 0, but that's what you know. So in a way, you have to visualize it. 
I use Hex, RGBA and RGB. Unless mass conversion is required, manually doing this will help you remember some odd 100 colors and their codes. 
For mass conversion write some script like one given by Alarie. Have a blast with Colors.

Answer (score -3):

how about using an :after pseudo-element?

```css
#myDiv{
  position: relative;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#myDiv:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  /* here you go */
  margin: -8px;
  border: solid 8px #00f;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">hello world!</div>
```

Comment: The question is "Is there any terse way of writing partially transparent colors in hexadecimal?". This doesn't seem even vaguely in the ballpark of answering that. It is much, much more verbose then the CSS 2 way the question mentioned: `background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);`

Answer (score -4):

why not use 
`background-color: #ff0000;
 opacity: 0.5; 
 filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* in IE */`

if you target a color for a text or probably an element, this should be a lot easier to do.

Comment: -1 opacity affect all of the content, not just the background-color

Comment: then the object can be doubled, one should be the containing element, the other should be the one inside the container that has opacity. because from the question the user wants another method than the conventional rgba.

Comment: He still wants the same result, and I'd better use rgba() or any other notation than modifying HTML.

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for, leave the hex colors alone and change the opacity using the `opacity` css property.