# Does IE support a proprietary semi-transparent CSS hexidecimal color code?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, colors, transparency, rgba

I was playing around with [this gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#5b5b5b+0,ffffff+100&0.5+0,0+100;Custom) and noticed that in the filter property, they use a variation of the common place hexidecimal color code:

```
#00ffffff
```

to seemingly acheive an rgba effect:
[Permalink](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#5b5b5b+0,ffffff+100&0.5+0,0+100;Custom)

I also saw this method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/891366/552067).
Does this work in IE? What versions of IE support this?

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015302/css-hexidecimal-rgba), but the answers never really mentioned if IE supports it. They just said it's invalid.

If IE does support this then it really makes no sense to use semi-transparent PNGs. Right?

Answer (score 5):

The color code `#00ffffff` stands for 0x00 alpha, 0xFF red, 0xFF green and 0xFF blue. This basically means completely transparent white. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532879.aspx) has a nice description of this notation.

The `#AARRGGBB` notation is used by MSIE filters only, and should be supported by IE5.5+ within the (`-ms-`)`filter` functions. It's not a valid color expression in CSS, so cannot be used with `color`, `background-color` et al, not even in IE.

Indeed, the use of gradient filters is a common workaround for CSS3 `rgba()` and gradients for older versions of IE which don't support them. However, as filters often cause layout problems (which I shan't elaborate on), many including myself opt to use semitransparent PNGs as background images instead.

Comment: I actually just learned about this yesterday, funny it should come up.  I hate having to edit colors in Photoshop instead of a CSS file. What's a good resource for learning about the filter-related layout problems you mention?

Comment: @Madmartigan: I don't have any resources, sadly - it was part hearsay and part personal experience. The "layout" I mention refers to `hasLayout`, so that could be an excellent search term to use.

Comment: Hello from the future! As a somewhat relevant note, the CSS Color Module Level 4 will *probably* support 4 and 8-digit hexadecimal RGBA notation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27802062/1317805

Comment: @James Donnelly: Eeyup, been a long time coming. I hope it gets implemented.