# get google maps v3 to make feature completely transparent

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are searching for a way to set the styles on google v3 map so that a given feature - such as water - is transparent (ie shows through to the background beneath the holding div)... ?

We have tried with setting the styling with something like this:

```
var styles = [
      {
        featureType: "water",
        stylers: [
          { color: none }
        ]
      }]
map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

but this simply sets the color to the map default which is light blue... when what we want is to see the background layer underneath the whole map...

thanks

Comment: Cannot see it working, but transparency is easily achieved by using an rgba color 'color:rgba(0,0,255,.5)'. But if there is a blue layer behind that, then you need to get a hold of that area as well.

Comment: thanks Rafe - can you set element styles with rgba? i can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: An rgba color only works for a flat colour. It sets the alpha transparency of a solid colour hence the letters. As I said, I cannot see how you can solve your issue, but was just offering an idea for you to play with.

Comment: Ok - cool. I'll see where that takes me and get back to you if i can see a way through.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) (works best in chrome). You can play with all options. So maybe this is what you need:

```
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
```

Sadly it seems that opacity is not a [supported styler](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#stylers).

Comment: Hi FrVaBe - funny: i was just playing with that - but "off" sets the colour to an off white colour which is not transparent it seems sadly

Comment: @user1051849 It seems that opacity is not supported.

Comment: You may be able to use the rgba colour idea with it though. If you can set the colour, it should be achievable. Didn't even think of this.

Comment: hmm - i gave it a go but it seems it only takes hex colour codes: i can't seem to format it to take rgba. Can you guys make it work? seems like a perfect solution if so!

Comment: I tried to use a hex color with opacity (e.g. {color: '#0C0000FF'} as describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8254129/367285). It seems to have an effect (color will be brighter) but I can not see that opacity works.

Comment: yeah - that would have been great - shame it doesn't quite work. neat trick i didn't know about though.

Comment: I also never touched rgba so far. Thanks to @Rafe for mentioning this possibility. But actually it seems not to be supported (documentation only mentions rgb color values).

Comment: @FrVaBe was close! To set opacity to a hex color in your styles, _prepend_ the alpha as two-digit hex.  E.g. 50% red would be: { color: '#80FF0000' }, with '80' meaning 50% alpha of 'FF0000'