# rgba(0,0,255,0.5) as hexadecimal color value?

Tags: css

With the following I can make a background semi transparent with CSS but its contense NOT be semi transparent.

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
```

Can you do the same thing with hexadecimal color values?

Comment: You can calculate the rgb values from your hex values (http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm) or you can change the `opacity` of your element.

Comment: @Alexander Scholz: That changes the opacity of the entire element including its contents, not its background only.

Comment: Okay misunderstood the question. But the first part of my comment is right.

Comment: you can use background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS hexidecimal RGBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015302/css-hexidecimal-rgba)

Comment: @Alexander Scholz: That's also totally irrelevant. The OP is using RGBA colors and is looking for a way to obtain the hex notation for it.

Comment: @ravi patel: Why? The OP wants blue, not black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, [you cannot](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color):

> Unlike RGB values, there is no hexadecimal notation for an RGBA value.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is no exact match we can get any color with transparency can be done as below

lets day it is black;

> rgb(0,0,0)

if we want 50% shade such as rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
we can do
#0009 or #000A

#0001 will be very transparent like 5% shade and #000F is like opacity 1

Here is the range of shades

> #0000 is transparent black
> #0001 .. #0009
> #000A .. #000F

Comment: yeah, you are right.  there is a step ~0.067