# background-color: transparent shows as background-color: #0000 in Safari and IE11 browsers

Tags: css, safari, internet-explorer-11, background-color

The background color for some buttons appears to be black and when I checked the value in the browser, it shows as `#0000`, whereas my CSS has `background-color: transparent`, I tried changing the opacity to 0, but even that doesn't seem to work.

Note: I am not using any `background-image`: url property, its just `background-color`.
I tried searching here for other answers but they don't seem to work.

Hamburger icon:

[image: Hamburger icon]

My CSS:

```
.menu-toggle {
  background-color: #0000;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: .2em;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

Whereas in my code I have written it to be transparent.

Comment: have you tried **background-color:transparent !important;** ?

Comment: yes I tried this as well

Comment: The snippet you posted contains "background-color: #0000;"? So 1. where does this snippet come from and where is your css with "background-color: transparent;" and 2. is #0000 even a valid color notation? Aren't they either 3 hex digits for RGB or 6 digits for RRGGBB?

Comment: can you add your html code here? It will be helpful

Comment: and background-color:#0000; is not a valid property!! It won't work

Comment: @Holzchopf: It is valid, but it's relatively new. Presumably the snippet is what's reflected in the inspector, since he claims that what he wrote is different.

Comment: @BoltClock: thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

The 4-digit hex notation `#0000` is new to CSS Color level 4 and has been supported in Safari since version 10. It is valid CSS, and has been [pretty widely supported for almost a year now](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa).<sup>1</sup> You can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015302/css-hexadecimal-rgba/27802062#27802062). I don't know why Internet Explorer 11 is showing that notation to you, considering the Color 4 spec wasn't even published at the time it was released (the FPWD was published in 2016, nearly *three years later*). Not even Microsoft Edge has any support for any of the new color notations yet.

Nevertheless, it's pretty typical of browsers to reflect computed values in a different notation to what you have specified, as long as you're not looking at `window.getComputedStyle()` or the Computed Values section of the inspector. The `transparent` keyword, the notation `#0000`, and the notation `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` all equal the same value, so don't worry that the browser might be changing your CSS.

---

<sub>Or *over two years* if you count it being available behind the experimental features flag from Chrome 52 to 61.</sub>