# Hex transparency color not visible on iPhone (safari/Chrome)

Tags: iphone, css, colors, transparency

**Scenario :**

- Built an Angular 6 app and used the color '#000000b0' as a background.

**Problem :**

- this was working perfectly on desktop but was not coming up on my iPhone.

Wondering to see if anyone else saw this behavior? 
Any solutions **(other than using rgba for color)**?

check a sample on https://www.akberiqbal.com/colors.htm ... the hexadecimal color code with transparency dissappears. I am using iOS 9.3.2 - will check on newer iPhones too.

Wanted to document this case to help someone else.

Thank You.

[image]

Comment: Hex color should have 6 digits after # not 8

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802062/746736

Comment: the browser can interpret group of 3, for instance instead of #000000 you can write #000 and it will be black in both examples

Comment: ok, cool I'll test that

Comment: @Alqbal This demo works for me in iOS Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/dskj3v54/7/. Please could you create a [MCVE]

Comment: Should be supported from iOS 10 on, according to https://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

Comment: @Turnip sample on: https://www.akberiqbal.com/colors.htm - Also updated the question

Comment: @misorude my phone screen is too small for jsfiddle :(

Comment: @AIqbal to small for the result view either? https://jsfiddle.net/dskj3v54/7/embedded/result/

Comment: Your demo page works fine for me @AIqbal

Comment: @misroude blank yellow screen, both squares on top are invisible

Comment: @Turnip your iOS version?

Comment: I am on iOS 11.4.1. Are you sure this isn't a caching issue? Does the JSFiddle work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/dskj3v54/7/embedded/result/

Comment: As per https://caniuse.com/#search=rgba - although the document is draft ( https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation )... the reason that an 8digit hexadecimal color code is not visible on any browser on my iphone is because of my iOS being older than 10.3;

Comment: @Turnip not a caching issue... for the jsfilddle shared by misroude, i saw a blank yellow screen, both squares on top are invisible on the iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per caniuse.com/#search=rgba - although the document is draft ( drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation )... the reason that an 8digit hexadecimal color code is not visible on any browser on my iphone is because of my iOS being older than 10.3;

The 8-digit hexadecimal color code (with transparency) just disappears on version older than 10.3

rgba would be the way to go because we still have a lot of older devices with old iOS version