# Stripe Element's ::placeholder opacity cannot be changed

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, stripe-payments, payment

Stripe React elements' placeholders have an `Opacity: 1` CSS property, that cannot be changed using the style object. Other `::placeholder` CSS properties can be changed.

Style object:

```
const iframeStyles = {
        base: {
            color: "#276678", //$blue
            fontSize: "30px",
            lineHeight: "38px",
            fontFamily: "Lato",
            fontWeight: 400,
            "::placeholder": {
              color: "#C8D7DE", //$bluepastel
              opacity: 0,
            }
          },
          invalid: {
          },
          complete: {
          }
    };
```

Firefox inspect output:

[image]

I have tried `!important`, but it didn't work. The opacity prop just doesn't apply. Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stripe.js' styling api limits which css properties you can modify. You cannot set `opacity`. They probably don't want you to make anything disappear. The documentation lists which css properties you may override.

https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style

You could try adding `00` to the color value instead. This will turn the color code to rgba, and the two last hex digits is the opacity of the color.

```
         color: "#C8D7DE00", //$bluepastel (invisible)
```

Comment: Thinking about it, it is an understandable decision from Stripe. RGBA color is the way to go.

Comment: Useful HEX opacity table here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8254129/1904943 . If you define a Stripe.com INPUT element (e.g. "card") as a variable (`var elements = stripe.elements(); ...`) - sample code here: https://github.com/bradtraversy/php_stripe_paypage/blob/master/js/charge.js - then you can style the input placeholder text, opacity per https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style , e.g. `... '::placeholder' : { color: #8000807F } ... ` , where `#800080` is HEX for the color purple, and `7F` is 50% opacity.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using card for **Stripe** in **React Native** so you can add this for **Placeholder Color**.

```
cardStyle={{
      textColor: '#000000', // use this actual Text
      placeholderColor: '#A9A9A9' // use this for Placeholder
    }}
```

Full code for card Field.

```
<CardField
    postalCodeEnabled={false}
    placeholders={{
      number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
    }}
    cardStyle={{
      textColor: '#000000',  // use this actual Text
      placeholderColor: '#A9A9A9' // use this for Placeholder
    }}
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: 50,
      marginVertical: 30,
    }}
    onCardChange={cardDetails => {
      fetchCardDetails(cardDetails)
    }}
    onFocus={focusedField => {
    }}
  />
```