# need transparency in my box-shadow with HEX color inside variable

Tags: css

```
:root {
    --r-link-color-rgb: rgb(19, 218, 236);
    --r-link-color-hex: #13DAEC;
}

box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(var(--r-link-color-rgb), 0.5); <--- this works    
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(var(--r-link-color-hex), 0.5); <--- of course this doesn't works
```

What can be done ? I have to find a solution to use hex values only. No SASS possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330997/8620333

Comment: Closed, but there's another solution as well. Using 8 digits hex. In your case `#13DAEC7F`, the last 2 digits `7F` means opacity 0.5.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8254129/9853981

Comment: @LSE you cannot add 2 digits to a CSS variables so it's not really a solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh, nvm then. Looks like it only works with strings https://jsfiddle.net/k2u8ov93/

Comment: @LSE doesn't work