# meteor pass blaze property to css (.less)

Tags: css, meteor, less, meteor-blaze

I have a document with a color property that I want to use as the background for a div. I currently do the following and it works:

```
<li class="task" style="background-color: {{statusColor}}">
```

The color is saved as a hex value and I would like to add transparency to it. I read that it is possible to do this with less:

```
.task{
  @result: fade(red, 50%);
  background-color: @result;
}
```

Is there a way to use the {{statusColor}} as the argument for the fade() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that less can add transparency with `fade()`. The problem with that approach is that less is part of the meteor build process and therefor cannot possibly know which document's `statusColor` to use. In other words, your `.less` files are compiled to `.css` at build-time, not run-time.

So you either need to store your colors in `rgb` format so that you can use `background-color: rgba(r,g,b,a);` or do the conversion on the front-end.

Here is some code to convert from hex to rgba: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663620/211727

You could use it in a helper like this:

```
Template.task.helpers({
    statusColorRGBA: function(hex) {
        return 'rgba(' + parseInt(hex.slice(-6,-4),16)
        + ',' + parseInt(hex.slice(-4,-2),16)
        + ',' + parseInt(hex.slice(-2),16)
        +',0.5)';
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<li class="task" style="background-color: {{statusColorRGBA statusColor}}">
```

FYI, there is currently no way to specify in alpha channel with hex notation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31029864/211727