# How to set a background opacity without affecting the text

Tags: html, css, transparency

I am basically trying to create this:[image]

Added a parent container with a background image,then a child container that needs to be transparent.

Here my HTML:

```
<div class="scent-brand-contact">
    <div class="scent-brand-container">               
       <section id="black-studio-tinymce-8" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-odd widget widget_black_studio_tinymce">
            <div class="textwidget">
                <p>All our fragrances are developed in compliance with the International Fragrance Association ensuring strict adherence to safety purity and manufacturing standards.</p>
                <p>LEARN MORE ABOUT HOW SCENT BRANDING CAN BENEFIT YOUR BUSINESS</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="text-4" class="widget-2 widget-last widget-even widget widget_text">
            <div class="textwidget">
            <button type="button">contact us today</button>
            </div>
        </section>                    
   </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.scent-brand-contact{
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(images/lemon.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height:380px;
}
.scent-brand-container {
    background-color: #fff9c0;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 285px;
}
```

At the moment,it's happening that the button and the texts are also getting the opacity.
How can I have the transparent background without affecting the text and the button?

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`rgba`](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) to make only the background color transparent, e.g.:

```
background: rgba(255, 249, 192, 0.7);
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, How can we add alpha , if we are getting dynamic color as theme= #4e74f0 (hex format). and we are adding it to element as - $().css('background", theme) , $().css('opacity',0.1).  Here, instead of opacity, how we can give alpha same as rgba

Comment: Well, if browser compatibility isn't a thing, you could use alpha hex values (check [here](https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31029864/4952806))