# CSS issue with edge

Tags: html, css

```
.background-red {
    background-color: #ff6767d4;
}
```

On Microsoft Edge (not the Chromium one), this color is not being rendered correctly.
How can I use CSS to use the following IF it's Edge

```
.background-red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hex is 6 symbols, not 8

Comment: Hex with 8 Symbols is also valid syntax, it specifies opacity with the last 2 values.

Comment: @cloned You can even use `color: #TFUBLYN`, but if your browser is not supporting wrong values, then it will simply ignore whole rule.

Comment: @cloned Just tested, you are correct. Could come in useful, cheers.

Comment: To see all the possibles way to define a color and the browser's support of them : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just write:

```
.background-red {
    background-color: red;
    background-color: #ff6767d4;
}
```

The last working value will be used. If a browser doesn't understand a value it will fall back to the last one that it understands.

Edit: You can also use `rgba()` to define your color, as far as I know edge supports this format.

Comment: your answer worked. I have to wait 10 min to accept it

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419448/hex-representation-of-a-color-with-alpha-channel) answer and [caniuseit table](https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa) IE does not support hex value with alpha channel. That's why it's ignoring whole rule.

To apply non valid values, you must set fallback for it. **Note the order** - browser will use last known rule when encountering invalid value.

```css
.background-red {
    background-color: rgba(255, 103, 103, .83);
    background-color: #ff6767d4;
}
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to be background-color: rgba(255, 103, 103, `0.83`);